# How to setup python flask web project with react on glitch?

Tags: python, reactjs, installation, glitch-framework

I want to build a **static web page** based on **python** as server side and **React** for frontend on [**glitch**](https://glitch.com/) online programming environment but unable to do .
I tried to implement by using **CDN link** but unable to use efficiently . Apart from this, I also wanted to use **MATERIAL UI** but according to there [website](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/) it says

> Using this approach in production is discouraged though - the client has to download the entire library, regardless of which components are actually used, affecting performance and bandwidth utilization.

**Please elaborate steps to do the same.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If it's a static site, why use Python? At the time of writing, glitch offers static site projects with no start-up time and no backend.

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry if that's too simple, but I managed to do it reading this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/build-deploy-a-react-flask-app-47a89a5d17d9

I use the framework Flask, but if you are using Django the process must be similar.

But I recomend building a API with python and communicate with the front-end through the fecth API from javascript, or axios on react. You'll even be able to work on the frontend and backend in two different servers if you want.